# How To Hide URL in struts1.x

Tags: struts-1

I am using struts 1.3 to develop my web application.I want to show static url(for every request url same) in client side.Can any one please tell me the solution.
Thanking you.

With Regards
Suresh

Comment: Please elaborate in detail.

Comment: add some code that you have tried